# Segmentation fault using argv[1]

Tags: c

I created a code that inserts and deletes nodes from a Linked List depending on what a .txt file instructs. I previously used scanf("%s",fname) to open the file but now I want to open it using the command line, specifically argv[1] == file name to open it and read from it. Now that I decided to use this I keep getting a segmentation fault. Any ideas why this is occurring? I just started taking a C course in my University and am brand new to it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node{
int val; 
struct node *next; 
} Node;

void count_node(Node *head){
     Node *temp;  
      int i=0;
     temp = head;
      while(temp!=NULL){
      i++;
      temp=temp->next;
     }
     printf("number of nodes are %d \n ",i);
  }
 void displayList(Node *head){
    Node *temp;
    temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL){
printf(" %d ",temp->val);
temp = temp->next;
    }
}
Node * findBefore(Node *head,int value){ 
    Node *curr = head; 
    Node *prev = NULL; 
    while(curr != NULL){
       if(value <= curr->val){
            return prev; 
        }
    prev = curr; 
    curr = curr->next; 
    /*printf("a\n");
    break;*/  
}
return prev;     // 1 2 4 
//printf("b\n");
}

void add(Node *head,int newValue){  //return a Node 0 for some reason 
ask TA
    printf("check \n");
    Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node)); 
    if(newNode == NULL){
    printf("check \n");
    return; 
    }
    newNode->val = newValue; 

     //if list is empty: 
    if(head == NULL){ 
        printf("check \n");
        head = newNode; 
    }
    //if list is not empty: 
    Node *prev = findBefore(head,newNode->val); //a -> b 
if(prev == NULL){
    printf("check \n");
    newNode->next = head; 
    head = newNode; 
    return; 
}
printf("check \n");
Node *temp = prev->next; 
prev->next = newNode; 
newNode->next = temp; 
}


void delete(Node *head, int delVal){
    if(head == NULL){
    return; 
 }
Node *prev = NULL; 
Node *curr = head; 

if(delVal == curr->val && prev !=NULL ){ // 1 2
        prev->next = curr->next; 
        free(curr); 
        return; 
    }
    else if(delVal == curr->val && prev == NULL){ // 1
        head = NULL; 
        free(curr); 
        return; 
    }

while(curr != NULL) {

    while(curr != NULL && curr->val != delVal){
        prev = curr; 
        curr = curr->next; 
    }

    if (curr == NULL){
        return; 
    }
    prev->next = curr->next; 
    free(curr);
    curr = prev->next; 
 }
}
int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {   
FILE * fp;
char singleLine[150];  
char command;  
int val;
fp = fopen(argv[1],"r"); 

if(fp == NULL ){
    exit(1); 
}
Node *head = malloc(sizeof(Node)); 
if(head == NULL){ //malloc returns null is there is a memory leak 
    return 1; 
}
while(fgets(singleLine,100,fp)){
    //printf("%s\n",singleLine); 
    sscanf(singleLine,"%c %d",&command,&val); 
    //printf("command character is: %c\n" , command); 
    //printf("The value we have to add is: %d\n",val);
    if(command == 'i'){
        printf("Found i, and add %d\n",val); 
        add(head,val); 
    }
    else if(command == 'd'){
        delete(head,val); 
        printf("found d and delete %d\n",val); 
    }
}
free(head); 
fclose(fp);
printf("\n"); 
count_node(head);  
printf("The linked list is : \n "); 
displayList(head); 
return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to add that before using argv[1] to open the file the program was working.

Comment: Did you pass any command line arguments to the program? If you didn’t, argv[1] won’t be a valid string.

Comment: of course. Which is why i can't seem to figure out why it wont work.

Comment: Well, you might want to double check that the arguments are being passed correctly. You could print out argc as a start to check if it is 2 (program name + single argument).

Comment: Off-topic to the question but your comment "malloc returns null if there is a memory leak" is not correct, it returns NULL if there isn't a large enough contiguous block of memory assignable to your process.

Comment: Thanks! Don't worry if its off topic. Everything helps me understand and get better!

Comment: Note that calls like 'void add(Node *head,int newValue)' cannot modify arguments like 'Node *head', so assignments inside the function like 'head = newNode;' only change the local parameter, NOT the passed argument.

Comment: And `Node *head = malloc(sizeof(Node));` --> `Node *head = NULL;`, `newNode->val = newValue;` --> `newNode->val = newValue; newNode->next = NULL;`

Answer (score 0):

What is the command you are using to run the program? Especially in larger projects, when we need to deal with external input, it's good practice to check it's validity.

Maybe something like:

```
if (argc < 2) { 
  println("Invalid input: No arguments");
  return 1;
}
char *filename = argv[1];
fp = fopen(filename,"r");
```

To see what may be the reason the call is failing. Try to add this short debug code *before* your call to `argv[1]`:

```
println("Number of arguments: %d", argc);
for (int i = 0, i < argc, i++) {
    println("Argument %d: \"%s\"", i, argv[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The program runs but for some reason after a certain point it return segmentation fault again. I just don't seem to understand why going to argv[1] = file name from taking in an input is causing so much change?

Comment: Sometimes rewriting code does the trick... The code also does a lot dereferencing pointers without safety checks (like `NULL` checks). I don't have a C compiler at hand, but maybe it would also help to understand the flow if you add more debug prints (that would turn into failure blocks) before (or after) calls to dangerous functions like `fopen`.